# Post search not looking at post title since 4.4.2 upgrade

Tags: custom-post-types, search

looks like searching for posts on my custom post type isn't checking in the title of the job anymore.

Worked fine before the update but now only searches the post content.

Any ideas?

This is the section for the job title:

```
array(
    'key'     => 'job_title',
    'value'   => $_GET['keywords'],
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
```

Comment: probably never searched in the title, or you don't show the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not include custom post types in its search by default. You can include specific CPT using pre_get_posts. In your functions.php:

```
/**
 * Include custom post type in Search
 */

function cpt_include_search($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ( is_search() && $query->get( 's' ) ) {

            // add your CPT in the array
            $query->set(
                'post_type', array('post', 'page', 'job'),
                'meta_query', array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'job_title',
                        'value' => '%s',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                )
            );
        }
    }
 return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_include_search' );
```

Also: make sure your CPT is registered in a way that makes it searchable.
Specifically those 2 lines:

```
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you nested two `if` clauses?

Comment: Yes: I usually have one function to manage all the `pre_get_posts`. Since `pre_get_posts` is triggered at EVERY request, the first `if` clause is to quickly get out of the function if I don't need it, e.g. if the request is triggered from the admin, or the query is not the one linked to the url.

Comment: Okay, cool. Just wanted to clarify for this answer :)